# nth factor of $\frac {1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots( m-1) } {( z+1) ( z+2) \cdots ( z+m-1) }m^{s}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Author of this book i am reading claims that the nth factor of 
$$\frac {1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots( m-1) } {( z+1)( z+2) \cdots( z+m-1) }m^{s}$$ is 
$\frac {n} {z+n}( \frac {n+1} {n}) ^{s}$ shouldn't it be just $$\frac {n} {z+n}( n+1) ^{s} ?$$

Edit:
The author claims the product would look like 
$$\prod _{n=1}^{n=m-1}\frac {n} {z+n}\left( \frac {n+1} {n}\right) ^{s}.$$ I think (most likely incorrectly) that it should be written as 
$$\prod _{n=1}^{n=m-1}\frac {n} {z+n}\left({n+1} \right) ^{s}$$

i think i can see my mistake so i am going to close the post.

Comment: Please define $n^{th}$ factor.

Comment: Well the expression could be rewritten as a product, nth factor would be the nth term of that product.

Comment: Even that is not good enough :-) As there are probably multiple ways of writing it as a product (multiplication being commutative and all). I am guessing you mean when we write out the product using $\prod_{n=1}^{m-1} f(n)$, we are talking about the two different $f(n)$ you mention in the question and whether the two products are the same.

Comment: sorry that was a typo in the denominator, i guess s is some constant

Comment: @Hardy: When you ask a question kindly add details to the questions so that the readers understand what is being asked and why is it tagged linear-algebra?

Comment: The product of the $\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^s$ simplify to $m^s$.

Comment: @alex.jordan i am not convinced that it is the case hence my post. unless my definitions of the products are incorrectly compiled.

Comment: @SivaramAmbikasaran the reason I tagged it as linear algebra is because it is just to do with an algebraic manipulation only.

Comment: @Aryabhata thanks for the pointer about defining the product i have now any thoughts ?

Comment: @J.D: I don't think number-theory (which is for more advanced topics) and factoring are appropriate here. It is a question about how to write using $\prod$ and I believe algebra-precalculus would be apt.

Comment: @Arturo Thanks i did n't not double dollars put the equations on new lines. I have been meaning to find out how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is right.

What your product gives us  is

$$\dfrac {1.2.3\ldots \left( m-1\right) } {\left( z+1\right) \left( z+2\right) \ldots \left( z+m-1\right) }(m!)^{s}$$

Note that it is $(m!)^s$ and not $m^s$.

Comment: Yes u r right the author is indeed right the correct product expression should be $\left( \prod _{n=1}^{n=m-1}\dfrac {n} {z+n}\right)\left( \dfrac {m+1} {m}\right) ^{s}$ Do u concur ?

Comment: @Hardy: No, that is not right. Now instead of $m^s$ you have $(\frac{m+1}{m})^s$.

Comment: yes that was blunder indeed. thanks i think i got the answer i was looking for before i embarrass myself more. I'll conclude this thread. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @Hardy: You are welcome. Mistakes are the best way to learn! So don't be embarrassed.